# Softwares for drawing hyperbolic surfaces , closed, with boundaries or with punctures?

Tags: diagrams

In a paper I am in the process of writing in LaTeX, I need to draw and incorporate some diagrams of hyperbolic surfaces in my LaTeX document. Is there any software I can use to draw hyperbolic surfaces, either closed, or with boundaries or punctures ? Are there any such freely downloadable softwares that I can use to draw such diagrams ? Please let me know if you know one. I apologize if this is off-topic. Thank you !

Comment: Hi TeXTex, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's a reasonable question- can you give an example of such a surface? Presumably it'll be in the form `f(x,y)=....`? If so, either `tikz` or `PStricks` will almost certainly do the job.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Is there any easy way to draw a ruled surface like a hyperbolic paraboloid in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19921/is-there-any-easy-way-to-draw-a-ruled-surface-like-a-hyperbolic-paraboloid-in-ti)

Answer (score 3):

When you are writing in LaTeX, basically there is a package for everything. Especially for plotting there is the beautiful `pgfplots` package: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/

Here's an example:

```
\begin{figure}[h!t]
\centering
%%% Declare tikspicture enviroment %%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %%% Declare axes %%%
    \begin{axis}[axis background/.style={fill=blue!10}]
    %%% Declare 3D surface, work on samples to adjust the quality %%%
    \addplot3[surf,domain=0:360,samples=40]
        {sin(x)*sin(y)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Which gives as result:
[image]