# Draw a paraboloid and its contours in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I have two similar images in which paraboloid and its contours are drawn.

[image: paraboloid1]

[image: paraboloid2]

What I've ever tried is in the following code that is very different from the figure.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={(current bounding box.north
    east) rectangle (current bounding box.south west)}}}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{120}{-25}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw [thick] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node {y} (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node {x} (0,0,0) -- (0,0,10) node {z};
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{-25}
\draw [red, thick, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node {y} (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node {x} (0,0,0) -- (0,0,10) node {z};
\fill [cyan, tdplot_rotated_coords, canvas is xy plane at z=0, opacity=0.67] (0,0) circle [radius=3];
\fill [cyan, tdplot_rotated_coords, canvas is xz plane at y=0, opacity=0.67] plot [variable=\x, domain=-3:3, samples=50] ({\x},{9-\x*\x});
\foreach \r in {1,2,3}
\draw [red, very thick, canvas is xy plane at z=0] (0,0) circle [radius=\r];
\node [below] at (0,3,0) {10};
\node [below] at (3,0,0) {10};
\node [left] at (0,0,9) {100};

\begin{scope}
\clip [canvas is xy plane at z=6] (0,0) circle [radius={sqrt(3)}] [reverseclip];
\fill [orange, canvas is xy plane at z=6] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to draw more realistic figure?

Comment: You're not really drawing a 3d figure (or a contour) here, rather a snapshot of what your object would look like from this point of view. Try redoing the diagram as a mesh of the function, the apply transparency by [fill opacity=0.8], and then clipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using `pgfplots`; something like that:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$, 
xmin=-19, xmax=19,
ymin=-19, ymax=19,
zmin=-1, zmax=110,
x={(-0.125cm,-0.05cm)}, y={(0.125cm,-0.05cm)}, z={(0cm,0.05cm)},
axis lines=middle,
every axis x label/.style={  at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},  },
every axis y label/.style={  at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},  },
every axis z label/.style={  at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},  },
]
% Paraboloid
\addplot3[surf,
shader=flat, draw=lightgray, fill=green, ultra thin, 
left color=green, right color=green, middle color=green!25, 
opacity=0.5, fill opacity=0.5,
data cs=polar, domain=0:360, 
y domain=0:10,
restrict z to domain=0:101, 
](x, y, 100-y^2);

% Plane 
\addplot3[surf, shader=faceted,
color=orange, 
opacity=0.01, fill opacity=0.4, 
domain=-10:10, 
](x,y,75);

% Circle at plane
\addplot3[red, smooth, 
domain=0:360, variable=\t
]({5*cos(\t)},{5*sin(\t)},{75});

% Circles at xy-plane
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{10, 7, 2.5}{%%
\pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{#1}
\addplot3[red, smooth, 
%no markers,
%samples=55,% samples y=0, 
domain=0:360, variable=\t
]({\Radius*cos(\t)},{\Radius*sin(\t)},{0});
}%%

% Annotations 1/2
\coordinate[label=](A) at ({7*cos(135)},{7*sin(135)},{0});
\coordinate[label=](B) at (8, -8, 75);
\coordinate[label=](C) at (-4, 5, 40);
\coordinate[label=](D) at({5*cos(300)},{5*sin(300)},{75});
\end{axis}

% Annotations 2/2
\draw[semithick] (A) -- +(45:2) node[right, align=left]{
$f(x,y)=51$\\ (a typical\\ level curve in\\ the function's\\ domain)};

\draw[semithick] (B) -- +(135:0.75) node[above, align=left]{
Plane $z=75$};

\draw[semithick] (C) -- +(45:3) node[above]{$z=100-x^2-y^2$};

\draw[semithick] (D) -- +(122:2.5) node[above, align=left, xshift=2cm]{The contour curve $f(x,y)=100-x^2-y^2=75$ \\ is the circle $x^2+y^2=25$ in the plane $z=75$.};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to draw the figure with the help of [adipro's answer to: How to draw a paraboloid in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156906/how-to-draw-a-paraboloid-in-tikz).

**First code:**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}
    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1, yscale=0.50, font=\Large]
\def\a{4};
\draw [red, very thick] (\a,0) circle [radius=\a];
\draw [red, very thick] (\a,0) circle [radius=0.7*\a];
\draw [red, very thick] (\a,0) circle [radius=0.5*\a];
\fill [red] (\a,0) circle [radius=3pt, yscale=2];
    
\shadedraw [draw=black, thick, left color=green, right color=green, middle color=green!25, opacity=0.33] ({\a-sqrt(\a*\a-1/(\a*\a))},{1/\a}) parabola bend (\a,{\a*\a+1/(\a*\a)}) ({\a+sqrt(\a*\a-1/(\a*\a))},{1/\a}) arc ({asin(1/\a/\a)}:{-180-asin(1/\a/\a)}:\a);
    
\draw [thick] ($(\a,0)+(4.2,4.2)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(3.57,3.57)$);
\draw [thick, dashed, dash pattern=on 5.6pt off 5.6pt] ($(\a,0)+(3.45,3.45)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(-2.80,-2.80)$);
\draw [thick, -Stealth] ($(\a,0)+(-2.85,-2.85)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(-4.5,-4.5)$) node [left=-0.5mm] {$x$};
    
\draw [thick] ($(\a,0)+(-4.5,4.5)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(-3.575,3.575)$);
\draw [thick, dashed, dash pattern=on 5.6pt off 5.6pt] ($(\a,0)+(-3.45,3.45)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(2.8,-2.8)$);
\draw [thick, -Stealth] ($(\a,0)+(2.85,-2.85)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(4,-4)$) node [right=-0.5mm] {$y$};
    
\draw [thick, dashed, dash pattern=on 5.6pt off 5.6pt] ($(\a,0)+(0,-1.5)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(0,\a*\a-1/2)$);
\draw [thick, -Stealth] ($(\a,0)+(0,\a*\a-1/3)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(0,18)$) node [left=-0.5mm] {$z$};
\fill [cyan]($(\a,0)+(0,\a*\a-1/3)$) circle [radius=3pt, yscale=2];
    
\draw [thick] ($(\a,0)+(-2.85,-2.85)$) -- ++(0pt,15pt);
\node [below=2.5pt] at ($(\a,0)+(-2.85,-2.85)$) {10};
\draw [thick] ($(\a,0)+(2.85,-2.85)$) -- ++(0pt,15pt);
\node [below=2.5pt] at ($(\a,0)+(2.85,-2.85)$) {10};
\draw [semithick] (3.7,-4.1) -- ++(-60:2) node [below] {$f(x,y)=0$};
\draw [semithick] (3.2,1.95) -- ++(109:9) node [above] {$f(x,y)=75$};
\draw [semithick] (6.85,0.4) -- ++(45:2.5) node [right, align=left] {$f(x,y)=51$\\ (a typical\\ level curve in\\ the function's\\ domain)};
\draw [semithick] (5.75,10) -- ++(58:2.5) node [right, align=left] {The surface\\ $z=f(x,y)$\\ \phantom{$-$}$=100-x^2-y^2$\\ is the graph of $f$.};
\draw [semithick] ($(\a,0)+(0,\a*\a-1/3)+(45:4pt)$) -- ++(45:1) node [right] {100};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**First figure:**
[image: paraboloid1]

**Second code:**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1, yscale=0.50, font=\Large]
\def\a{4};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{0.75*\a*\a}
\draw [red, very thick, dashed, dash pattern=on 5.6pt off 5.6pt] (\a,0) circle [radius=0.5*\a];

\shadedraw [draw=black, thick, left color=green, right color=green, middle color=green!25, opacity=0.33] ({\a-sqrt(\a*\a-1/(\a*\a))},{1/\a}) parabola bend (\a,{\a*\a+1/(\a*\a)}) ({\a+sqrt(\a*\a-1/(\a*\a))},{1/\a}) arc ({asin(1/\a/\a)}:{-180-asin(1/\a/\a)}:\a);

\draw [thick] ($(\a,0)+(4.2,4.2)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(3.57,3.57)$);
\draw [thick, dashed, dash pattern=on 5.6pt off 5.6pt] ($(\a,0)+(3.45,3.45)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(-2.80,-2.80)$);
\draw [thick, -Stealth] ($(\a,0)+(-2.85,-2.85)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(-4.5,-4.5)$) node [left=-0.5mm] {$x$};

\draw [thick] ($(\a,0)+(-4.5,4.5)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(-3.575,3.575)$);
\draw [thick, dashed, dash pattern=on 5.6pt off 5.6pt] ($(\a,0)+(-3.45,3.45)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(2.8,-2.8)$);
\draw [thick, -Stealth] ($(\a,0)+(2.85,-2.85)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(4,-4)$) node [right=-0.5mm] {$y$};

\draw [thick, dashed, dash pattern=on 5.6pt off 5.6pt] ($(\a,0)+(0,-1.5)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(0,7)$) ($(\a,0)+(0,10.2)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(0,\a*\a-1/2)$);
\draw [thick, -Stealth] ($(\a,0)+(0,\a*\a-1/3)$) -- ($(\a,0)+(0,18)$) node [left=-0.5mm] {$z$};

\draw [thick] ($(\a,0)+(-2.85,-2.85)$) -- ++(0pt,15pt);
\node [below=2.5pt] at ($(\a,0)+(-2.85,-2.85)$) {10};
\draw [thick] ($(\a,0)+(2.85,-2.85)$) -- ++(0pt,15pt);
\node [below=2.5pt] at ($(\a,0)+(2.85,-2.85)$) {10};

\draw [dashed, dash pattern=on 6pt off 6pt] ({\a-sqrt(\a*\a-1/(\a*\a))},{1/\a}) arc ({180-asin(1/\a/\a)}:{asin(1/\a/\a)}:\a);

\fill [orange, opacity=0.50] (-1,11.8) -- ++(5,-5) -- ++(4.7,4.7)  -- ++(-5,5) -- cycle;

\draw [red, very thick, dashed, dash pattern=on 5.6pt off 5.6pt] (1.50*\a,0.75*\a*\a) arc [start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=0.50*\a];
\shadedraw [draw=black, thick, left color=green, right color=green, middle color=green!25, opacity=0.10] (1.50*\a,0.75*\a*\a) parabola bend (\a,{\a*\a+1/(\a*\a)}) (0.50*\a,0.75*\a*\a) arc [start angle=180, end angle=360, radius=0.5*\a];
\draw [red, very thick] (0.50*\a,0.75*\a*\a) arc [start angle=180, end angle=360, radius=0.50*\a];
\draw [thick] ($(\a,0)+(0,\a*\a-1/3)$) node [left] {100} -- ++(8pt,0pt);
\draw [thick] ($(\a,0)+(0,\b)$) node [left] {75} -- ++(8pt,0pt);
\draw [semithick] (3.90,-2.2) -- ++(-70:3.4) node [below, align=left] {The level curve $f(x,y)=100-x^2-y^2=75$ \\ is the circle $x^2+y^2=25$ in the $xy$-plane.};
\draw [semithick] (0.8,11.8) -- ++(110:2.75) node [above] {Plane $z=75$};
\draw [semithick] (6.5,6.5) -- ++(75:8) node [above] {$z=100-x^2-y^2$};
\draw [semithick] (3.2,10.3) -- ++(110:9) node [above, align=left] {The contour curve $f(x,y)=100-x^2-y^2=75$ \\ is the circle $x^2+y^2=25$ in the plane $z=75$.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Second figure:**

[image: paraboloid2]

Answer (score 1):

Draw it in `inkscape` and import to LaTeX. You can save it as `pstricks` picture or `tikz` picture code. `Pstricks` need `xelatex` to compile. Here is example of `tikz` code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{cb9d9c0}{RGB}{185,217,192}
\definecolor{c8cd9c0}{RGB}{140,217,192}
\definecolor{cfce0a8}{RGB}{252,224,168}
\definecolor{cfce3ab}{RGB}{252,227,171}
\definecolor{cff0000}{RGB}{255,0,0}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-32.01988,-26.65196)},opacity=0.288,transparency group]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-32.01988,-26.65196)}]
    \path[fill=cb9d9c0,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
      width=0.161pt] (104.3783,44.9346) -- (49.2649,138.9067) -- (159.4916,138.9067)
      -- cycle;
    \path[draw=c8cd9c0,fill=cb9d9c0,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter
      limit=4.00,line width=0.161pt] (49.2649,138.9067) .. controls
      (55.2911,98.6213) and (76.9704,67.0133) .. (91.2895,52.2007) .. controls
      (96.6722,46.6325) and (102.2947,45.1596) .. (104.3783,44.9346);
    \path[draw=c8cd9c0,fill=cb9d9c0,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter
      limit=4.00,line width=0.161pt] (49.2649,138.9067) .. controls
      (58.7199,168.1684) and (152.3115,167.5824) .. (159.4916,138.9067);
    \path[draw=c8cd9c0,fill=cb9d9c0,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter
      limit=4.00,draw opacity=0.995,line width=0.161pt] (159.4916,138.9067) ..
      controls (153.4654,98.6213) and (131.7862,67.0133) .. (117.4670,52.2007) ..
      controls (112.0843,46.6325) and (106.4618,45.1596) .. (104.3783,44.9346);
    \path[draw=cfce0a8,fill=cfce3ab,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter
      limit=4.00,line width=0.161pt] (36.7438,83.6156) -- (92.7460,38.6360) --
      (172.5715,58.7257) -- (124.3918,108.5056) -- cycle;
    \path[draw=cff0000,dash pattern=on 0.16pt off 0.16pt,line join=miter,line
      cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.161pt] (76.0343,71.7930) .. controls
      (86.5965,56.6895) and (120.4663,55.4382) .. (133.1032,71.6210);
    \path[draw=cff0000,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
      width=0.161pt] (76.0343,71.7930) .. controls (86.5965,86.8966) and
      (124.1064,87.3077) .. (133.1032,71.9650);
    \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 0.16pt off 0.16pt,line join=miter,line
      cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.161pt] (49.2649,138.9067) .. controls
      (72.2488,103.0780) and (141.8639,108.1076) .. (159.4916,138.9067);
    \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
      width=0.161pt] (32.1214,118.6394) -- (51.3222,123.9728);
    \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
      width=0.161pt] (152.1262,150.2850) -- (180.5718,157.5742);
    \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 0.32pt off 0.16pt,line join=miter,line
      cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.161pt] (53.1718,124.5209) --
      (149.6879,149.5062);

    \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 0.32pt off 0.16pt,line join=miter,line
      cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.161pt] (126.3474,117.5727) --
      (85.0569,157.9742);
    \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
      width=0.161pt] (83.5944,159.4376) -- (66.6117,176.7750);
    \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 0.32pt off 0.16pt,line join=miter,line
      cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.161pt] (104.8398,137.5323) --
      (104.8807,102.9054);
    \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 0.32pt off 0.16pt,line join=miter,line
      cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.161pt] (104.8398,82.5955) --
      (104.7882,50.4248);
    \path[draw=c8cd9c0,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,draw
      opacity=0.996,line width=0.161pt] (76.0343,71.7930) .. controls
      (83.3359,60.7691) and (96.9122,44.7693) .. (104.3783,44.9346) .. controls
      (113.5053,44.7411) and (123.7077,57.8811) .. (133.1032,71.6210);
    \path[draw=c8cd9c0,fill=cb9d9c0,line join=round,line cap=rect,miter
      limit=4.00,line width=0.003pt] (102.3095,82.7912) .. controls
      (96.0937,82.4259) and (89.9402,80.9277) .. (85.1977,78.6242) .. controls
      (81.9030,77.0240) and (78.9724,74.8137) .. (77.1490,72.5540) --
      (76.5496,71.8111) -- (76.8266,71.3986) .. controls (76.9791,71.1716) and
      (77.2516,70.8308) .. (77.4326,70.6418) .. controls (77.6135,70.4523) and
      (77.7432,70.2498) .. (77.7205,70.1912) .. controls (77.6636,70.0433) and
      (78.0237,69.6065) .. (78.1597,69.6587) .. controls (78.2211,69.6815) and
      (78.3855,69.5819) .. (78.5255,69.4357) .. controls (78.7348,69.2172) and
      (78.7604,69.1467) .. (78.6700,69.0375) .. controls (78.5573,68.9015) and
      (78.5898,68.7928) .. (78.8259,68.5180) .. controls (78.9544,68.3684) and
      (78.9698,68.3696) .. (79.1513,68.5408) -- (79.3419,68.7200) --
      (79.5910,68.4600) -- (79.8402,68.2000) -- (79.6462,67.9275) .. controls
      (79.5347,67.7711) and (79.4807,67.6078) .. (79.5194,67.5435) .. controls
      (79.7503,67.1578) and (80.9757,65.3173) .. (82.3727,63.5473) .. controls
      (83.5844,62.0122) and (84.9421,60.5688) .. (85.6891,59.6981) .. controls
      (88.2861,56.6717) and (91.4755,53.1418) .. (93.6316,51.2072) .. controls
      (97.7456,47.5158) and (101.2522,45.6334) .. (103.8071,45.3817) --
      (104.4424,45.3191) -- (104.4424,47.7307) -- (104.4424,50.1422) --
      (104.8423,50.1422) -- (105.2422,50.1422) -- (105.2422,47.7574) --
      (105.2422,45.3724) -- (105.8422,45.4515) .. controls (108.5198,45.8037) and
      (111.5148,47.1648) .. (114.7327,49.8270) .. controls (118.7826,53.1774) and
      (123.2502,58.5369) .. (128.6118,65.9565) -- (130.0507,67.9478) --
      (129.8249,68.1839) .. controls (129.5427,68.4780) and (129.5438,68.5036) ..
      (129.8420,68.7670) .. controls (130.1446,69.0332) and (130.2738,69.0412) ..
      (130.4024,68.8011) .. controls (130.4991,68.6202) and (130.5082,68.6236) ..
      (130.7079,68.9121) .. controls (130.8962,69.1846) and (130.9018,69.2227) ..
      (130.7739,69.3666) .. controls (130.6453,69.5111) and (130.6549,69.5453) ..
      (130.8928,69.7939) .. controls (131.0509,69.9589) and (131.2125,70.0482) ..
      (131.3081,70.0232) .. controls (131.4742,69.9776) and (131.8218,70.3793) ..
      (131.7621,70.5460) .. controls (131.7450,70.5972) and (131.8935,70.8162) ..
      (132.0943,71.0347) .. controls (132.7995,71.8027) and (132.7938,71.7252) ..
      (132.2058,72.5782) .. controls (130.9527,74.3962) and (129.3339,75.9439) ..
      (127.2126,77.3519) .. controls (122.6512,80.3797) and (116.4315,82.2300) ..
      (109.0192,82.7643) .. controls (107.8932,82.8457) and (103.5189,82.8645) ..
      (102.3078,82.7928) -- cycle(105.2430,81.8750) -- (105.2430,81.0749) --
      (104.8430,81.0749) -- (104.4431,81.0749) -- (104.4431,81.8750) --
      (104.4431,82.6750) -- (104.8430,82.6750) -- (105.2430,82.6750) --
      cycle(105.2430,79.5638) -- (105.2430,78.7637) -- (104.8430,78.7637) --
      (104.4431,78.7637) -- (104.4431,79.5638) -- (104.4431,80.3638) --
      (104.8430,80.3638) -- (105.2430,80.3638) -- cycle(105.2430,77.2526) --
      (105.2430,76.4525) -- (104.8430,76.4525) -- (104.4431,76.4525) --
      (104.4431,77.2526) -- (104.4431,78.0526) -- (104.8430,78.0526) --
      (105.2430,78.0526) -- cycle(105.2430,75.0303) -- (105.2430,74.2303) --
      (104.8430,74.2303) -- (104.4431,74.2303) -- (104.4431,75.0303) --
      (104.4431,75.8303) -- (104.8430,75.8303) -- (105.2430,75.8303) --
      cycle(105.2430,72.7191) -- (105.2430,71.9191) -- (104.8430,71.9191) --
      (104.4431,71.9191) -- (104.4431,72.7191) -- (104.4431,73.5191) --
      (104.8430,73.5191) -- (105.2430,73.5191) -- cycle(105.2259,70.4745) --
      (105.2543,69.6967) -- (104.8509,69.6967) -- (104.4476,69.6967) --
      (104.4476,70.5018) -- (104.4476,71.3070) -- (104.8253,71.2786) --
      (105.2031,71.2501) -- cycle(105.2430,68.1807) -- (105.2430,67.3758) --
      (104.8209,67.4042) -- (104.3987,67.4327) -- (104.3703,68.0911) .. controls
      (104.3532,68.4529) and (104.3643,68.8032) .. (104.3874,68.8689) .. controls
      (104.4158,68.9446) and (104.5809,68.9884) .. (104.8363,68.9884) --
      (105.2391,68.9884) -- cycle(129.3298,67.7261) -- (129.5380,67.4445) --
      (129.2496,67.1868) .. controls (128.9691,66.9365) and (128.9560,66.9336) ..
      (128.7831,67.0895) .. controls (128.4258,67.4126) and (128.4030,67.5680) ..
      (128.6795,67.7939) .. controls (129.0135,68.0670) and (129.0835,68.0602) ..
      (129.3303,67.7262) -- cycle(80.7768,67.4940) -- (81.0675,67.2516) --
      (80.8297,66.9183) -- (80.5919,66.5849) -- (80.2728,66.8221) .. controls
      (80.0970,66.9530) and (79.9382,67.0713) .. (79.9195,67.0855) .. controls
      (79.8797,67.1140) and (80.3746,67.7253) .. (80.4423,67.7313) .. controls
      (80.4651,67.7335) and (80.6175,67.6267) .. (80.7774,67.4935) --
      cycle(128.1229,66.8125) -- (128.3562,66.5064) -- (128.0581,66.2794) ..
      controls (127.8942,66.1543) and (127.7241,66.0524) .. (127.6797,66.0530) ..
      controls (127.6342,66.0536) and (127.5051,66.1998) .. (127.3896,66.3773) ..
      controls (127.2218,66.6361) and (127.2041,66.7146) .. (127.3008,66.7698) ..
      controls (127.3674,66.8097) and (127.5016,66.9007) .. (127.5995,66.9758) ..
      controls (127.8435,67.1635) and (127.8583,67.1590) .. (128.1229,66.8119) --
      cycle(82.2187,66.3733) .. controls (82.2193,66.3278) and (82.1362,66.1600) ..
      (82.0344,65.9950) -- (81.8489,65.6952) -- (81.5833,65.8510) .. controls
      (81.1594,66.0997) and (81.1389,66.1674) .. (81.3807,66.5231) --
      (81.6026,66.8497) -- (81.9098,66.6506) .. controls (82.0788,66.5414) and
      (82.2176,66.4162) .. (82.2182,66.3730) -- cycle(105.2430,65.8692) --
      (105.2430,65.0643) -- (104.8209,65.0928) -- (104.3987,65.1212) --
      (104.3703,65.8991) -- (104.3419,66.6769) -- (104.7897,66.6769) --
      (105.2374,66.6769) -- cycle(126.8366,66.0194) .. controls (127.0841,65.6195)
      and (127.0756,65.5819) .. (126.6870,65.3633) -- (126.3519,65.1750) --
      (126.1528,65.5209) -- (125.9537,65.8668) -- (126.2859,66.0927) .. controls
      (126.4685,66.2167) and (126.6255,66.3185) .. (126.6346,66.3185) .. controls
      (126.6460,66.3185) and (126.7348,66.1837) .. (126.8360,66.0193) --
      cycle(83.2527,65.7788) .. controls (83.5400,65.6013) and (83.5463,65.5859) ..
      (83.4217,65.3567) .. controls (83.1480,64.8520) and (83.1532,64.8543) ..
      (82.8064,65.0688) .. controls (82.4383,65.2963) and (82.4320,65.3202) ..
      (82.6419,65.6888) .. controls (82.8263,66.0131) and (82.8644,66.0188) ..
      (83.2526,65.7787) -- cycle(125.5760,65.1690) -- (125.7751,64.8208) --
      (125.4770,64.6365) .. controls (125.3132,64.5352) and (125.1419,64.4521) ..
      (125.0970,64.4521) .. controls (125.0071,64.4521) and (124.7107,64.9164) ..
      (124.7107,65.0577) .. controls (124.7107,65.1339) and (125.2011,65.4912) ..
      (125.3330,65.5105) .. controls (125.3558,65.5142) and (125.4667,65.3604) ..
      (125.5765,65.1692) -- cycle(84.4815,65.0654) .. controls (84.8388,64.8544) and
      (84.8513,64.8128) .. (84.6619,64.4475) .. controls (84.5026,64.1397) and
      (84.4064,64.1261) .. (84.0247,64.3588) -- (83.7408,64.5317) --
      (83.9359,64.8907) .. controls (84.0435,65.0881) and (84.1385,65.2503) ..
      (84.1481,65.2508) .. controls (84.1595,65.2513) and (84.3074,65.1678) ..
      (84.4815,65.0648) -- cycle(124.1467,63.9001) .. controls (123.7559,63.6890)
      and (123.6677,63.7032) .. (123.5126,64.0030) .. controls (123.3203,64.3751)
      and (123.3368,64.4269) .. (123.7106,64.6198) -- (124.0440,64.7922) --
      (124.2357,64.4224) -- (124.4274,64.0526) -- cycle(85.8686,64.3609) --
      (86.2214,64.1811) -- (86.0410,63.8278) .. controls (85.9420,63.6332) and
      (85.8430,63.4745) .. (85.8209,63.4745) .. controls (85.7116,63.4745) and
      (85.1529,63.7834) .. (85.1529,63.8437) .. controls (85.1529,63.9325) and
      (85.4420,64.5415) .. (85.4841,64.5415) .. controls (85.5011,64.5415) and
      (85.6741,64.4607) .. (85.8681,64.3617) -- cycle(105.2430,63.6519) --
      (105.2430,62.8519) -- (104.7987,62.8519) -- (104.3543,62.8519) --
      (104.3543,63.5926) .. controls (104.3543,64.0000) and (104.3827,64.3601) ..
      (104.4135,64.3927) .. controls (104.4476,64.4268) and (104.6462,64.4519) ..
      (104.8579,64.4519) -- (105.2430,64.4519) -- cycle(122.8716,63.7822) ..
      controls (122.9541,63.6092) and (123.0213,63.4505) .. (123.0213,63.4283) ..
      controls (123.0213,63.4056) and (122.8597,63.3066) .. (122.6628,63.2059) --
      (122.3044,63.0233) -- (122.1337,63.4044) -- (121.9631,63.7856) --
      (122.2475,63.9375) .. controls (122.6469,64.1508) and (122.7021,64.1372) ..
      (122.8712,63.7828) -- cycle(87.5534,63.5450) .. controls (87.5534,63.4773) and
      (87.3099,62.9504) .. (87.2422,62.8702) .. controls (87.2137,62.8361) and
      (86.4868,63.1285) .. (86.4868,63.1763) .. controls (86.4868,63.1991) and
      (86.5658,63.3703) .. (86.6631,63.5603) -- (86.8395,63.9056) --
      (87.1968,63.7657) .. controls (87.3930,63.6883) and (87.5540,63.5893) ..
      (87.5540,63.5455) -- cycle(121.4636,63.2116) .. controls (121.5381,63.0671)
      and (121.5990,62.9055) .. (121.5990,62.8514) .. controls (121.5990,62.7610)
      and (121.0818,62.4959) .. (120.9049,62.4959) .. controls (120.8235,62.4959)
      and (120.5653,63.1882) .. (120.6290,63.2344) .. controls (120.7280,63.3061)
      and (121.1228,63.4626) .. (121.2189,63.4677) .. controls (121.2786,63.4710)
      and (121.3890,63.3556) .. (121.4635,63.2117) -- cycle(88.6460,63.1661) ..
      controls (88.9560,63.0363) and (88.9589,63.0307) .. (88.8610,62.7121) ..
      controls (88.7387,62.3138) and (88.6397,62.2717) .. (88.2276,62.4441) --
      (87.9034,62.5795) -- (88.0393,62.9049) .. controls (88.1139,63.0841) and
      (88.1753,63.2457) .. (88.1753,63.2639) .. controls (88.1753,63.3293) and
      (88.3352,63.2980) .. (88.6458,63.1661) -- cycle(120.0801,62.5776) .. controls
      (120.1404,62.3773) and (120.1763,62.2032) .. (120.1609,62.1907) .. controls
      (120.1154,62.1566) and (119.5334,61.9637) .. (119.4667,61.9637) .. controls
      (119.3989,61.9637) and (119.1674,62.6728) .. (119.2186,62.7238) .. controls
      (119.2829,62.7881) and (119.6925,62.9303) .. (119.8297,62.9360) .. controls
      (119.9202,62.9396) and (120.0106,62.8108) .. (120.0806,62.5776) --
      cycle(90.0557,62.6606) .. controls (90.4209,62.5514) and (90.4215,62.5497) ..
      (90.2081,61.9802) .. controls (90.1473,61.8175) and (90.0892,61.7874) ..
      (89.9311,61.8363) .. controls (89.4037,62.0007) and (89.3140,62.0576) ..
      (89.3667,62.1953) .. controls (89.3952,62.2726) and (89.4446,62.4319) ..
      (89.4742,62.5497) .. controls (89.5357,62.7938) and (89.5806,62.8023) ..
      (90.0553,62.6601) -- cycle(118.5672,62.2971) .. controls (118.7760,61.7384)
      and (118.7737,61.7211) .. (118.4779,61.6179) .. controls (118.0552,61.4705)
      and (117.9818,61.4927) .. (117.8747,61.7994) .. controls (117.7251,62.2289)
      and (117.7512,62.2949) .. (118.1102,62.3903) .. controls (118.2934,62.4415)
      and (118.4544,62.4830) .. (118.4681,62.4881) .. controls (118.4795,62.4932)
      and (118.5261,62.4074) .. (118.5671,62.2976) -- cycle(91.4779,62.2158) ..
      controls (91.7266,62.1412) and (91.8113,62.0730) .. (91.7812,61.9711) ..
      controls (91.7584,61.8938) and (91.7135,61.7202) .. (91.6810,61.5854) ..
      controls (91.6151,61.3072) and (91.6236,61.3100) .. (91.1753,61.4346) ..
      controls (90.8169,61.5342) and (90.7890,61.6064) .. (90.9397,62.0389) ..
      controls (91.0518,62.3598) and (91.0251,62.3513) .. (91.4779,62.2153) --
      cycle(105.2430,61.3413) -- (105.2430,60.5413) -- (104.7987,60.5413) --
      (104.3544,60.5413) -- (104.3544,61.3413) -- (104.3544,62.1414) --
      (104.7987,62.1414) -- (105.2430,62.1414) -- cycle(117.0968,61.9851) ..
      controls (117.1196,61.9453) and (117.1656,61.7729) .. (117.1986,61.5966) ..
      controls (117.2555,61.2939) and (117.2441,61.2694) .. (116.9711,61.1750) ..
      controls (116.5250,61.0197) and (116.4573,61.0481) .. (116.3519,61.4390) ..
      controls (116.3007,61.6392) and (116.2666,61.8156) .. (116.2819,61.8309) ..
      controls (116.3103,61.8594) and (116.8798,62.0295) .. (116.9936,62.0443) ..
      controls (117.0277,62.0487) and (117.0738,62.0215) .. (117.0966,61.9851) --
      cycle(93.2420,61.6597) .. controls (93.2417,61.6085) and (93.2021,61.4190) ..
      (93.1521,61.2427) -- (93.0628,60.9218) -- (92.6634,61.0134) .. controls
      (92.2265,61.1135) and (92.2191,61.1272) .. (92.3630,61.6055) --
      (92.4614,61.9349) -- (92.8517,61.8456) .. controls (93.0662,61.7944) and
      (93.2420,61.7131) .. (93.2414,61.6601) -- cycle(115.7175,61.3195) .. controls
      (115.8279,60.8843) and (115.8017,60.8427) .. (115.3648,60.7625) .. controls
      (115.0041,60.6965) and (114.9802,60.7170) .. (114.8971,61.1767) .. controls
      (114.8402,61.4924) and (114.8459,61.5027) .. (115.1742,61.5897) .. controls
      (115.3585,61.6409) and (115.5349,61.6830) .. (115.5656,61.6881) .. controls
      (115.5940,61.6931) and (115.6646,61.5277) .. (115.7169,61.3201) --
      cycle(94.7232,61.4014) .. controls (94.7573,61.3673) and (94.5975,60.7108) ..
      (94.5451,60.6587) .. controls (94.5224,60.6359) and (94.3323,60.6416) ..
      (94.1292,60.6758) .. controls (93.7594,60.7383) and (93.7594,60.7383) ..
      (93.8203,61.0615) .. controls (93.8545,61.2396) and (93.9022,61.4193) ..
      (93.9284,61.4620) .. controls (93.9682,61.5251) and (94.6520,61.4734) ..
      (94.7232,61.4023) -- cycle(114.1597,61.2745) .. controls (114.1825,61.2404)
      and (114.2246,61.0589) .. (114.2576,60.8769) .. controls (114.3145,60.5680)
      and (114.3031,60.5423) .. (114.0693,60.4906) .. controls (113.9328,60.4621)
      and (113.7524,60.4166) .. (113.6676,60.3939) .. controls (113.5476,60.3597)
      and (113.5021,60.4280) .. (113.4600,60.6908) .. controls (113.4316,60.8774)
      and (113.3991,61.0692) .. (113.3912,61.1175) .. controls (113.3852,61.1687)
      and (113.4970,61.2313) .. (113.6432,61.2626) .. controls (114.0341,61.3462)
      and (114.1171,61.3479) .. (114.1598,61.2740) -- cycle(96.1644,61.1107) ..
      controls (96.1815,61.0936) and (96.1701,60.9036) .. (96.1360,60.6851) --
      (96.0762,60.2875) -- (95.7474,60.3387) .. controls (95.3031,60.4058) and
      (95.2564,60.4667) .. (95.3281,60.8900) -- (95.3895,61.2541) --
      (95.7593,61.1972) .. controls (95.9630,61.1687) and (96.1445,61.1278) ..
      (96.1621,61.1124) -- cycle(112.7464,60.7045) .. controls (112.8152,60.2750)
      and (112.7805,60.2260) .. (112.3407,60.1595) .. controls (111.9886,60.1083)
      and (111.9140,60.2050) .. (111.9112,60.7353) .. controls (111.9102,60.9384)
      and (111.9510,60.9794) .. (112.1991,61.0101) .. controls (112.3578,61.0272)
      and (112.5330,61.0499) .. (112.5876,61.0613) .. controls (112.6445,61.0670)
      and (112.7139,60.9088) .. (112.7464,60.7057) -- cycle(97.6737,60.8479) ..
      controls (97.6908,60.8308) and (97.6772,60.6567) .. (97.6453,60.4582) ..
      controls (97.5884,60.1350) and (97.5577,60.0969) .. (97.3324,60.0969) ..
      controls (96.8192,60.0969) and (96.7128,60.2528) .. (96.8573,60.7916) ..
      controls (96.9085,60.9782) and (96.9467,60.9918) .. (97.2783,60.9372) ..
      controls (97.4797,60.9031) and (97.6584,60.8638) .. (97.6754,60.8485) --
      cycle(99.1542,60.2869) .. controls (99.1200,60.0599) and (99.0865,59.8710) ..
      (99.0791,59.8665) .. controls (99.0734,59.8622) and (98.8953,59.8779) ..
      (98.6876,59.9006) .. controls (98.3480,59.9347) and (98.3099,59.9638) ..
      (98.3110,60.1754) .. controls (98.3137,60.6999) and (98.3753,60.7692) ..
      (98.8122,60.7346) -- (99.2162,60.7005) -- cycle(111.2316,60.6078) .. controls
      (111.3585,60.1356) and (111.3067,60.0266) .. (110.9261,59.9623) .. controls
      (110.7276,59.9282) and (110.5455,59.9225) .. (110.5222,59.9453) .. controls
      (110.4994,59.9680) and (110.4556,60.1364) .. (110.4261,60.3185) .. controls
      (110.3641,60.6997) and (110.4659,60.8060) .. (110.8994,60.8083) .. controls
      (111.1139,60.8094) and (111.1902,60.7628) .. (111.2317,60.6098) --
      cycle(100.6729,60.5065) .. controls (100.6769,60.5010) and (100.6615,60.3267)
      .. (100.6388,60.1191) -- (100.5990,59.7413) -- (100.2082,59.7413) --
      (99.8173,59.7413) -- (99.8173,60.1265) .. controls (99.8173,60.3381) and
      (99.8458,60.5378) .. (99.8754,60.5697) .. controls (99.9209,60.6152) and
      (100.6286,60.5583) .. (100.6696,60.5065) -- cycle(109.7225,60.4894) ..
      controls (109.8227,60.2277) and (109.7817,59.8300) .. (109.6542,59.8300) ..
      controls (109.5871,59.8300) and (109.4096,59.8073) .. (109.2600,59.7731) ..
      controls (109.0040,59.7219) and (108.9846,59.7390) .. (108.9277,60.0394) ..
      controls (108.8936,60.2157) and (108.8936,60.4200) .. (108.9163,60.4939) ..
      controls (108.9886,60.6822) and (109.6465,60.6771) .. (109.7194,60.4882) --
      cycle(108.2113,60.4007) .. controls (108.2397,60.3233) and (108.2625,60.1236)
      .. (108.2625,59.9564) .. controls (108.2625,59.6566) and (108.2575,59.6526) ..
      (107.8723,59.6526) .. controls (107.4501,59.6526) and (107.3739,59.7345) ..
      (107.3739,60.1873) .. controls (107.3739,60.3956) and (107.4194,60.4473) ..
      (107.6185,60.4781) .. controls (108.0890,60.5492) and (108.1556,60.5406) ..
      (108.2091,60.4013) -- cycle(102.2206,60.3301) .. controls (102.2206,60.2630)
      and (102.1978,60.0827) .. (102.1637,59.9302) .. controls (102.1125,59.6696)
      and (102.0835,59.6526) .. (101.7194,59.6526) -- (101.3303,59.6526) --
      (101.3303,60.0525) -- (101.3303,60.4525) -- (101.7746,60.4525) .. controls
      (102.0926,60.4525) and (102.2189,60.4183) .. (102.2189,60.3301) --
      cycle(103.4724,60.3643) .. controls (103.6999,60.3643) and (103.7318,60.3301)
      .. (103.7318,60.1048) .. controls (103.7318,59.6457) and (103.6567,59.5644) ..
      (103.2334,59.5644) -- (102.8432,59.5644) -- (102.8432,59.9495) .. controls
      (102.8432,60.3717) and (102.9029,60.4837) .. (103.0901,60.4115) .. controls
      (103.1578,60.3830) and (103.3296,60.3660) .. (103.4724,60.3660) --
      cycle(106.7368,59.9865) -- (106.7653,59.5644) -- (106.3158,59.5644) --
      (105.8664,59.5644) -- (105.8664,59.9569) .. controls (105.8664,60.3921) and
      (105.9341,60.4519) .. (106.3995,60.4263) .. controls (106.7050,60.4092) and
      (106.7112,60.4035) .. (106.7374,59.9865) -- cycle(105.2430,59.3420) --
      (105.2430,58.3198) -- (104.7987,58.3198) -- (104.3544,58.3198) --
      (104.3544,59.3420) -- (104.3544,60.3643) -- (104.7987,60.3643) --
      (105.2430,60.3643) -- cycle(105.2430,56.8086) -- (105.2430,56.0086) --
      (104.7987,56.0086) -- (104.3544,56.0086) -- (104.3544,56.8086) --
      (104.3544,57.6086) -- (104.7987,57.6086) -- (105.2430,57.6086) --
      cycle(105.2259,54.5196) -- (105.1975,53.7418) -- (104.7975,53.7418) --
      (104.3976,53.7418) -- (104.3692,54.5196) -- (104.3407,55.2974) --
      (104.7919,55.2974) -- (105.2430,55.2974) -- cycle(105.2430,52.2751) --
      (105.2430,51.4751) -- (104.7987,51.4751) -- (104.3544,51.4751) --
      (104.3544,52.2751) -- (104.3544,53.0751) -- (104.7987,53.0751) --
      (105.2430,53.0751) -- cycle(105.2430,50.5862) .. controls (105.2430,50.4320)
      and (105.1838,50.4087) .. (104.7987,50.4087) .. controls (104.4135,50.4087)
      and (104.3544,50.4314) .. (104.3544,50.5862) .. controls (104.3544,50.7403)
      and (104.4136,50.7637) .. (104.7987,50.7637) .. controls (105.1838,50.7637)
      and (105.2430,50.7409) .. (105.2430,50.5862) -- cycle;
    \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
      width=0.161pt] (104.8399,44.5046) -- (104.8359,28.1468);
    \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
      width=0.161pt] (104.8399,44.5046) -- (104.8399,50.1302);
    \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
      width=0.161pt] (104.8354,47.7921) -- (106.7911,47.7921);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```