# How to draw a z-simple paraboloid in a "clean" way

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to draw `z=x^2+y^2` on the interval `0<z<9`. So normally I've just been using `pgfplots` with the `addplot3` command, and for rectangular domains that doesn't seem to cause too much trouble. Example (from [Is there any easy way to draw a ruled surface like a hyperbolic paraboloid in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19921/is-there-any-easy-way-to-draw-a-ruled-surface-like-a-hyperbolic-paraboloid-in-ti?lq=1)):

[image]

In my case, however, I'd like to draw a paraboloid and I'd like the edge of the curve to be at `r=3` in the `z=9` plane. My first attempt was something like this (adapted from previous question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-3,ymin=-3,zmin=0,xmax=3,ymax=3,zmax=10]
\addplot3 [surf,draw=none,restrict z to domain=0:9] {x^2+y^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly the domain causes a problem: the paraboloid doesn't print pretty at all because the last z value evaluated is not at `z=9`, it is rather somewhere close to that below `z=9`, varying for each pair of coordinates (x,y).

I could set `samples y=300`, but the compilation time will be insane. Also, it limits the possibilities of the document, since I'm consuming a lot of stack size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-3,ymin=-3,zmin=0,xmax=3,ymax=3,zmax=10]
\addplot3 [surf,draw=none,restrict z to domain=0:9,samples y=300] {x^2+y^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Surely there's a better way to do this?

Comment: You have to switch to polar description of the surface to make the level sets parallel to the xy plane. Then you can cut the surface in a sane fashion. Pgfplots don't know how to chop off the mesh in the middle to limit the visible region.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As percusse said in the comment, you could use polar coordinates:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-3,ymin=-3,zmin=0,xmax=3,ymax=3,zmax=10]
\addplot3 [surf,draw=none,restrict z to domain=0:9, data cs=polar, domain=0:360, y domain=0:3] (x, y, y^2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```