# Polar coordinates in tikz-\addplot3

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I am failing to display a paraboloid with tikz `\addplot3` command. I read a [thourough manual](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Esimardr/pgfplots.pdf) that I found online as well as tried to adapt [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239750/226018), but I don't really understand how to translate my function into polar coordinates, as it seems.
The level curves of my paraboloid, with the function equation:

[image: level curves]

My **code** for the 3d-plot:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={Sammansatta nivåkuror, botten på $(0,0,1)$},
        axis lines=center,
        axis on top,
        colormap/cool,
        xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    ]
    \addplot3[
        surf,
        samples=50,
        domain=0:360,
        y domain=0:3,
        restrict z to domain=0:10,
        data cs=polar
    ] (x, y, {sqrt(x^2+2*y^2)+1});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

What it outputs:

[image]

What the 3d-plot should look like (but the function is off):

[image]

I obtained the latter by modifying the following:

```
\addplot3[
   ...
] (x, y, y^2)
```

Also, the last 3d-plot displays up to different values of z depending on my screenwidth, which I do not really understand. I am using Overleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your formula x and y are cartesian coordinates (as I suppose) then you should not use `data cs=polar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
                   title={Sammansatta nivåkuror, botten på $(0,0,1)$},
                   axis lines=center,
                   axis on top,
                   colormap/cool,
                   xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
                   ]
              \addplot3[
                        surf,
                        samples=50,
                        % domain=0:360,
                        % y domain=0:3,
                        % restrict z to domain=0:10,
                        % data cs=polar
                        ] {sqrt(x^2+2*y^2)+1};
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
             \end{document}
```

[image]